# How do I pass an en entity ID to another entity during the seeding process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this class:

```
public class Reservation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SpaceNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserName{ get; set; }

    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }

    public Reservation() { }
}
```

I am trying to setup some seeds, but am not sure how to pass the GameID to this. Here is an example:

```
public class TTUInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TTUContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(TTUContext context)
    {
        var reservation = new List<Reservation>
        {
            new Reservation{SpaceNumber=123, UserName="username", Game_ID=1},
            new Reservation{SpaceNumber=124, UserName="username", Game_ID=1},
        };
        reservation.ForEach(r => context.Reservations.Add(r));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Game_ID is the name of the database column - but when I tried adding that as a property, the migration generated a new (second) Game_ID1 column. what's the correct what to seed this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the Game instance and set the Game property to that instance. The Game_ID is the field used to hold the reference to the id of the Game, but this is the Entity framework, and it deals with entities, not id's. It's meant to be an abstraction, so if you need to set the reference ID's explicitly you need to hack the system and set that through ADO.NET.

Comment: No no, EF can deal with IDs alright. *And* with entities. If you do both it's called *foreign key associations*.

Comment: @GertArnold Ok. Sure, from the other answers I see that you can make a  property which is the actual foreign key for an entity reference. It still seems very hacky to use it like that however. In my mind, retrieve the the entity you want to reference and seed your data with a reference to that entity. Straight forward and your database is kept nicely abstracted away.

Answer (score 0):

To expose the ID of the related entity, you need to, as you guessed, define it as a property. You also, however, need to tell EF that this property is a foreign key.
Try to define the relationship in the model like this:

```
public class Reservation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SpaceNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserName{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Game")]
    public int GameID{ get; set;}
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }

    public Reservation() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new instance of Game if it doesn't exist, or get it from context if it does.

The `Game_ID` column doesn't *need* to be present as a property in your class (it may be usefull, but it's not a must-have), you can always use `Game.Id`, but of course when you create a relationship you need an instance of game.

```
var game = new Game{Id = 1};//or context.Games.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == 1);
```

and when instanciating your reservations

```
new Reservation{SpaceNumber=123, UserName="username", Game = game},
new Reservation{SpaceNumber=124, UserName="username", Game = game},
```